# Flask Error: No such command "fab" when installing Superset

Tags: python, flask, floating-action-button, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I'm following the steps of the Superset installation guide carefully on Mac OS: https://superset.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization

When I run `flask fab create-admin`, I get the following error:

```
Try "flask --help" for help.

Error: No such command "fab".
```

I'm running Python 3.7.7. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You are running

`flask fab create-admin`

the correct command for that step is

`superset fab create-admin`.

It's in the [link you provided](https://superset.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization)